# Tcolorbox and lost floats

Tags: floats, tcolorbox

I use tcolorbox to write exercises with solutions for a book of probability. When I use some floats, like tables or figures, it refuses it, and I have error messages like `! LaTeX Error: Not in outer par mode.` or `Float(s) lost`.. so I'm obliged to undo the float command `begin{figure}.. \end{figure}` and use instead the `caption` package, and it's command 
`\captionof{figure}{The caption}`...

Now, I want to use floats in such cases. 1/ How can I use it ?

2/ Moreover, is it possible to use with `\NewTColorBox` some rotated tables, given by the package `ctable`, like this one, for example: ?

```
\ctable[
caption={Mycaption},
label={tab:Mytable},
botcap, % caption below table
sideways % This rotates the table
]
{ccc}
{
% Table footnotes here
}
{
Column 1 & Column 2 & Column 3 \\
Row 2, 1 & 2, 2     & 2, 3 \\
}
```

3/ More and moreover, can I write some things outside the box of solution, for writing some comments for example, or some floats !, between two successive solutions ?

I give an example of an exercise, where one can note that the commands `\begin{figure} \end{figure}` are commented, (there is the error `Not in outer par mode` when it is uncomented)

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox} 
\tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable,xparse}

\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable,xparse}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,backgrounds,plotmarks,calc,positioning,shadings,patterns,tikzmark}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

%\usepackage{ctable}% Uncomment If one wants to compile the ctable given as example
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}

\NewTColorBox[auto counter,number within=chapter]{exercise}{m+O{}}{%
    enhanced,
    colframe=green!20!black,
    colback=yellow!10!white,
    coltitle=green!40!black,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    underlay={\begin{tcbclipinterior}
        \shade[inner color=green!80!yellow,outer color=yellow!10!white]
            (interior.north west) circle (2cm);
        \draw[help lines,step=5mm,yellow!80!black,shift={(interior.north west)}]
            (interior.south west) grid (interior.north east);
        \end{tcbclipinterior}},
    title={Exercise~ \thetcbcounter:},
    label={exercise:#1},
    attach title to upper=\quad,
    after upper={\par\hfill\textcolor{green!40!black}%
        {\itshape Solution on page~\pageref{solution:#1}}},
    lowerbox=ignored,
    savelowerto=solutions/exercise-\thetcbcounter.tex,
    record={\string\solution{#1}{solutions/exercise-\thetcbcounter.tex}},
    #2
}

\NewTotalTColorBox{\solution}{mm}{%
    enhanced,
    colframe=red!20!black,
    colback=yellow!10!white,
    coltitle=red!40!black,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    underlay={\begin{tcbclipinterior}
        \shade[inner color=red!50!yellow,outer color=yellow!10!white]
            (interior.north west) circle (2cm);
        \draw[help lines,step=5mm,yellow!80!black,shift={(interior.north west)}]
            (interior.south west) grid (interior.north east);
        \end{tcbclipinterior}},
    title={Solution of Exercise~\ref{exercise:#1} on page~\pageref{exercise:#1}:},
    phantomlabel={solution:#1},
    attach title to upper=\par,
}{\input{#2}}

\tcbset{no solution/.style={no recording,after upper=}}

\begin{document}
%% Uncomment If one wants to compile this ctable
%%  \ctable[
%%  caption={Your table caption},
%%  label={tab:mytable},
%%  botcap, % caption below table
%%  sideways % This rotates the table
%%  ]
%%  {ccc}
%%  {
%%  % Table footnotes here
%%  }
%%  {
%%  Column 1 & Column 2 & Column 3 \\
%%  Row 2, 1 & 2, 2     & 2, 3 \\
%%  }
\chapter{The first chapter}
\tcbstartrecording
\begin{exercise}{BanachMatch}
The bar graph of the distribution of Banach matches..
\tcblower
%   \begin{figure}[h]
    {\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    declare function={
    comb(\n,\k)=\n!/(\k!*(\n-\k)!);
    albanach(\k,\n,\p)=comb(2*\n-\k,\n)*(\p^(\n+1)*(1-\p)^(\n-\k)+\p^(\n-\k)*(1-\p)^(\n+1));
    }
]
\begin{axis}[
    xlabel={$x$}, ylabel={$P(X=x)$},
    yticklabel style={
        /pgf/number format/fixed,
        /pgf/number format/fixed zerofill,
        /pgf/number format/precision=2
    },
    legend style={
cells={anchor=east},
legend pos=outer north east,
    xlabel={$x$}, ylabel={$P(X=x)$},samples at={0,...,50},
    yticklabel style={
        /pgf/number format/fixed,
        /pgf/number format/fixed zerofill,
        /pgf/number format/precision=2
                     }
              },
    ybar=0pt, bar width=2
]
\addplot [fill=orange, fill opacity=0.5] {albanach(x,50,0.5)}; \addlegendentry{$p=0.5$}
\addplot [fill=cyan, fill opacity=0.5] {albanach(x,50,0.4)}; \addlegendentry{$p=0.4$}
\addplot [fill=blue, fill opacity=0.5] {albanach(x,50,0.3)}; \addlegendentry{$p=0.3$}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\par}
\captionof{figure}{Banach matches}
%\end{figure}
\end{exercise}
\tcbstoprecording
\tcbinputrecords
\end{document}
```

and its compilation, using xelatex:
[image]

Comment: you want your tclorbox to be the _content_ of a figure so it floats, not have he figure inside a box (which is an error)

Comment: Too much (unrelated) questions in one post, in my point of view

Comment: The post above does not really need `xelatex`, in my point of view and if the colorboxes should float, use the `float` option to the boxes, however, sometimes it is not well-designed to let 'exercises' float away (the order might be important) and in bad occasions, the solution to an exercise can appear before the exercise if floating is allowed for both

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I attend to give a list of exercises for each chapter, after the list of all solutions, so the solution cannot appear before an exercise

Comment: @DavidCarlisle how can I insert then the figure into the solution if the solution is a tcolorbox ? More precisely, for the question in point  3/ More and moreover, can I write some things outside the box of solution, for writing some comments for example, or some floats !, between two successive solutions ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the nesting in the wrong order, you want your coloured boxes to float, so they should be inside `figure` you do not want `figure` to be inside the box.

this works without error

```
\begin{figure}[htp]
\begin{exercise}{BanachMatch}
```

....

```
\end{exercise}
\end{figure}
```

with no other changes needed to your document.

---

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox} 
\tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable,xparse}

\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable,xparse}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,backgrounds,plotmarks,calc,positioning,shadings,patterns,tikzmark}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

%\usepackage{ctable}% Uncomment If one wants to compile the ctable given as example
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}

\NewTColorBox[auto counter,number within=chapter]{exercise}{m+O{}}{%
    enhanced,
    colframe=green!20!black,
    colback=yellow!10!white,
    coltitle=green!40!black,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    underlay={\begin{tcbclipinterior}
        \shade[inner color=green!80!yellow,outer color=yellow!10!white]
            (interior.north west) circle (2cm);
        \draw[help lines,step=5mm,yellow!80!black,shift={(interior.north west)}]
            (interior.south west) grid (interior.north east);
        \end{tcbclipinterior}},
    title={Exercise~ \thetcbcounter:},
    label={exercise:#1},
    attach title to upper=\quad,
    after upper={\par\hfill\textcolor{green!40!black}%
        {\itshape Solution on page~\pageref{solution:#1}}},
    lowerbox=ignored,
    savelowerto=solutions/exercise-\thetcbcounter.tex,
    record={\string\solution{#1}{solutions/exercise-\thetcbcounter.tex}},
    #2
}

\NewTotalTColorBox{\solution}{mm}{%
    enhanced,
    colframe=red!20!black,
    colback=yellow!10!white,
    coltitle=red!40!black,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    underlay={\begin{tcbclipinterior}
        \shade[inner color=red!50!yellow,outer color=yellow!10!white]
            (interior.north west) circle (2cm);
        \draw[help lines,step=5mm,yellow!80!black,shift={(interior.north west)}]
            (interior.south west) grid (interior.north east);
        \end{tcbclipinterior}},
    title={Solution of Exercise~\ref{exercise:#1} on page~\pageref{exercise:#1}:},
    phantomlabel={solution:#1},
    attach title to upper=\par,
}{\input{#2}}

\tcbset{no solution/.style={no recording,after upper=}}

\begin{document}
%% Uncomment If one wants to compile this ctable
%%  \ctable[
%%  caption={Your table caption},
%%  label={tab:mytable},
%%  botcap, % caption below table
%%  sideways % This rotates the table
%%  ]
%%  {ccc}
%%  {
%%  % Table footnotes here
%%  }
%%  {
%%  Column 1 & Column 2 & Column 3 \\
%%  Row 2, 1 & 2, 2     & 2, 3 \\
%%  }
\chapter{The first chapter}
\tcbstartrecording
\begin{figure}[htp]
\begin{exercise}{BanachMatch}
The bar graph of the distribution of Banach matches..
\tcblower
    {\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    declare function={
    comb(\n,\k)=\n!/(\k!*(\n-\k)!);
    albanach(\k,\n,\p)=comb(2*\n-\k,\n)*(\p^(\n+1)*(1-\p)^(\n-\k)+\p^(\n-\k)*(1-\p)^(\n+1));
    }
]
\begin{axis}[
    xlabel={$x$}, ylabel={$P(X=x)$},
    yticklabel style={
        /pgf/number format/fixed,
        /pgf/number format/fixed zerofill,
        /pgf/number format/precision=2
    },
    legend style={
cells={anchor=east},
legend pos=outer north east,
    xlabel={$x$}, ylabel={$P(X=x)$},samples at={0,...,50},
    yticklabel style={
        /pgf/number format/fixed,
        /pgf/number format/fixed zerofill,
        /pgf/number format/precision=2
                     }
              },
    ybar=0pt, bar width=2
]
\addplot [fill=orange, fill opacity=0.5] {albanach(x,50,0.5)}; \addlegendentry{$p=0.5$}
\addplot [fill=cyan, fill opacity=0.5] {albanach(x,50,0.4)}; \addlegendentry{$p=0.4$}
\addplot [fill=blue, fill opacity=0.5] {albanach(x,50,0.3)}; \addlegendentry{$p=0.3$}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\par}
\captionof{figure}{Banach matches}
\end{exercise}
\end{figure}
\tcbstoprecording
\tcbinputrecords
\end{document}
```

Comment: After doing this, I have always the message 
`! LaTeX Error: Not in outer par mode.`
At all, in the exercise, the solution is given (which is defined after the command `\tcblower`) in another box. The question is then: Which box is inside the figure ?

Comment: @FaouziBellalouna I added the complete error free document

Comment: Thanks. It works and I accepted the answer. Have you any idea for how to write outside the box answer please !?

Comment: @FaouziBellalouna i am not sure what you mean but presumably you would also want to float your answers otherwise the questions will float past answers and be out of sequence (unless all your answers are at the end. In any case that seems to be a separate question/

Comment: I give for each chapter, a list of exercises in the section `\section{List of exercises}` , after their solutions, in a last section `\section{Answers for exercises}`

Comment: @FaouziBellalouna I do not understand in that case why you want the questions to float, what do you want them to float past?

Comment: I want to, perhaps, write some comments between the ansers of two exercises...
For example, some thing like `In the exercises from 3.5 to 3.9, we'll use the equation (2.7) that gives the derivative of the characteristic functions....`

Comment: sorry I do not understand your document design and as you will have seen the system is objecting to too many comments. I suspect that with the fancy box layout you do not want floats at all. If you have further questions, start a new question not more comments, the site system does not work for long comment discussion.

Comment: ok I'll open another question soon. Many thanks

Comment: Would you see the questions opened here, please. Thanks
http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/351606/tcolorbox-exercises-and-the-manyfoot-package
and
http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/351631/tcolorbox-exercises-and-the-manyfoot-package-2