# Tcolorbox, exercises and the manyfoot package

Tags: tcolorbox, manyfoot

I use the `tcolorbox` package to produce exercises with solution. I produce sometimes footnotes in the boxes in the usual way and, sometimes, when I have  several footnotes, I use the `manyfoot` package to write these footnote in "inlined" way. One can see in the compilation here that the usual footnotes are written inside the box, but not the footnotes produced by `manyfoot`, which gives only the sign of the footnote but not the footnote nor it's text. How can I obtain the same behaviour for the footnotes created by manyfoot, i.e. obtain the texts of footnotes, written inside the box of exercises, in inlined form, and in the box of the solution too?

I give the tex file used:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable,xparse}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}

\usepackage[para*]{manyfoot}
\DeclareNewFootnote[para]{C}
\makeatletter
\let\c@footnoteC\c@footnote
\makeatother

\renewcommand{\thefootnoteC}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}

\NewTColorBox[auto counter,number within=chapter]{exercise}{+O{}}{%
enhanced,colframe=green!20!black,colback=yellow!10!white,coltitle=green!40!black,
fonttitle=\bfseries,
underlay={\begin{tcbclipinterior}
\shade[inner color=green!80!yellow,outer color=yellow!10!white]
(interior.north west) circle (2cm);
\draw[help lines,step=5mm,yellow!80!black,shift={(interior.north west)}]
(interior.south west) grid (interior.north east);
\end{tcbclipinterior}},
title={Exercise~ \thetcbcounter:},
label={exercise@\thetcbcounter},
attach title to upper=\quad,
after upper={\par\hfill\textcolor{green!40!black}%
{\itshape Solution on page~\pageref{solution@\thetcbcounter}}},
lowerbox=ignored,
savelowerto=solutions/exercise-\thetcbcounter.tex,
record={\string\solution{\thetcbcounter}{solutions/exercise-\thetcbcounter.tex}},
#1
}

\NewTotalTColorBox{\solution}{mm}{%
enhanced,colframe=red!20!black,colback=yellow!10!white,coltitle=red!40!black,
fonttitle=\bfseries,
underlay={\begin{tcbclipinterior}
\shade[inner color=red!50!yellow,outer color=yellow!10!white]
(interior.north west) circle (2cm);
\draw[help lines,step=5mm,yellow!80!black,shift={(interior.north west)}]
(interior.south west) grid (interior.north east);
\end{tcbclipinterior}},
title={Solution of Exercise~\ref{exercise@#1} on page~\pageref{exercise@#1}:},
phantomlabel={solution@#1},
attach title to upper=\par,
}{\input{#2}}

\tcbset{no solution/.style={no recording,after upper=}}

\begin{document}
\chapter{The first chapter}
\section{Exercises}
\tcbstartrecording
\begin{exercise}
Exercise with inlined footnotes, \footnoteC{inlined footnote 1} and \footnoteC{inlined footnote 2}, in the question.
\tcblower
Exercise with inlined footnotes, \footnoteC{inlined footnote 1} and \footnoteC{inlined footnote 2}, in the answer.
\end{exercise}
\begin{exercise}
Exercise with usual footnotes, \footnote{footnote 1} and \footnote{footnote 2}, in the question.
\tcblower
Exercise with usual footnotes, \footnote{footnote 1} and \footnote{footnote 2}, in the answer.
\end{exercise}
\tcbstoprecording
\section{Solutions of exercises}
\tcbinputrecords
\end{document}
```

and it's compilation, using xelatex:

[image]

Comment: Your MWE is not compiling, you have local files which are not provided... `solutions/exercise-`

Comment: Sorry but this MWE compiles in my computer as I have published, and it does not used any one of my own files. Why doesn't it compile for you ?

Comment: @G.Bay The error that gives to me is `! I can't write on file `solutions/exercise-1.1.tex'.` so the file is an output, not an input. Faouzi, could you tell us how do you compile your code? I tried with XeLaTeX with `-shell-escape` but it doesn't work.

Comment: @FaouziBellalouna Maybe you can create a real MWE. In which you eliminate everything unrelated to the problem. A single box with about two footnotes should be sufficient.